# How to set wallpaper from Windows command prompt on Windows 10?

Tags: cmd

I've been trying to set my wallpaper in Windows 10 by doing the following in a command prompt window:

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d wallpaper_directory /f

RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
```

This works once, but then if I try to change the wallpaper soon after it, it does not work.

Am I doing something wrong or how do I fix this?

Comment: Have a look at this PowerShell solution: https://web.archive.org/web/20171211042726/http://www.culham.net/powershell/changing-desktop-wallpaper-using-windows-powershell/

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, "RUNDLL32.EXE USER32.DLL,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters" (with or without "1, True" or "2, True") leads to inconsistent results (at least on my PC). I found the following PowerShell script, that always works on my PC: https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=15291, option 2:

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------#
# ScriptName : SetWall.ps1                                          #
# Description : Force a Desktop wallpaper Refresh                   #
# Credits  : Unknown (if you know original creator, let us know)    #
#                                                                   #
# Date : 01 July 2020                                               #
#-------------------------------------------------------------------#

#Modify Path to the picture accordingly to reflect your infrastructure
$imgPath="\\Domain.lab\netlogon\Wallpaper.png"
$code = @' 
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 
namespace Win32{ 
    
     public class Wallpaper{ 
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)] 
         static extern int SystemParametersInfo (int uAction , int uParam , string lpvParam , int fuWinIni) ; 
         
         public static void SetWallpaper(string thePath){ 
            SystemParametersInfo(20,0,thePath,3); 
         }
    }
 } 
'@

add-type $code 

#Apply the Change on the system 
[Win32.Wallpaper]::SetWallpaper($imgPath)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple.

1. Go to `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Themes`. Find one image with name `TranscodedWallpaper`. Replace it with your image (don't keep extension).
2. Do the same thing inside `cachedFile` folder.
3. Execute `RUNDLL32.EXE USER32.DLL,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters ,1 ,True` to reload the wallpaper.